# Why wont my layout scroll to show content?

Tags: html, css

I've set all overflows as Auto, so on theory it should then allow me to scroll when the content takes up over 100% of the space. It's probably something blaringly obvious but any help would be appreciated!

http://www.marasites.com/?name=iSell&page=Style1

```html
<title>Marasite by iSell</title>

<body leftmargin='0' rightmargin='0' topmargin='0' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0'>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; cht=ISO-8859-1'>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

    <head>
        <link href='
        https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Quicksand' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0, padding: 0
            }
            
            div {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            
            html,
            body {
                height: 100%;
            }
            
            #container {
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
                background-color: #3d3c3a;
                font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
                font-size: 15px;
                color: #022a31;
                overflow: auto;
            }
            
            #container i {
                font-size: 15px;
                color: #022a31;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            
            #container b {
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: 700;
            }
            
            #container h1 {
                font-size: 24px;
                font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
                text-align: center;
                color: grey;
                margin: 0;
            }
            
            #container h1::first-letter {
                color: #2b3547;
            }
            
            #container h2 {
                font-size: 48px;
                font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
                text-align: center;
                color: grey;
                margin: 0;
            }
            
            #container h2::first-letter {
                color: #2b3547;
            }
            
            #container a {
                color: white;
                background-color: grey;
                text-decoration: none;
                padding: 3px;
                margin-top: 4px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
                -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
            
            #column1 {
                width: 25%;
                min-height: 100%;
                background-image: url("http://hdwallpaperia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Galaxy-Space-Stars-Wallpaper-Image.jpg");
                position: fixed;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
            }
            
            #c1box i {
                font-size: 12px;
                color: #3d5072;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            
            #c1box b {
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #07162f;
                font-weight: 700;
            }
            
            #c1box h1 {
                font-size: 16px;
                color: grey;
                font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
            }
            
            #c1box img {
                width: 150px;
                height: 150px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 2px;
                border-color: grey;
            }
            
            #c1box h1::first-letter {
                color: #2b3547;
            }
            
            #c1box a {
                color: white;
                background-color: grey;
                text-decoration: none;
                padding: 3px;
                margin-top: 4px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
                -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
            
            #c1box {
                height: 0;
                padding-bottom: 80%;
                width: 80%;
                margin: 10%;
                background-color: white;
                border: 3px solid #c1c1c1;
                text-align: center;
                -webkit-transition: .7s;
                -moz-transition: .7s;
                -o-transition: .7s;
                -ms-transition: .7s;
                transition: .7s;
            }
            
            #c1box:hover {
                opacity: 0.5;
            }
            
            #column2 {
                width: 50%;
                min-height: 100%;
                background-color: white;
                position: fixed;
                left: 25%;
                top: 0;
                border-left-style: solid;
                border-right-style: solid;
                border-left-width: 20px;
                border-right-width: 20px;
                border-left-color: #2b3547;
                border-right-color: #2b3547;
                overflow: auto;
                padding-left: 5px;
            }
            
            #column2 img {
                border: solid grey 2px;
            }
            
            #column3 {
                width: 25%;
                min-height: 100%;
                background-color: #e3e2e2;
                position: fixed;
                left: 75%;
                top: 0;
                overflow: auto;
                margin: 0;
                text-align: center;
            }
            
            #c3box {
                height: 100px;
                width: 100%;
                float: right;
                margin: 5%;
                margin-top: 11%;
                background-color: white;
                padding: 10px;
                -webkit-transition: .7s;
                -moz-transition: .7s;
                -o-transition: .7s;
                -ms-transition: .7s;
                transition: .7s;
                color: #0D254F;
                display: inline-block;
                float: right;
                line-height: 1.5em;
                border: 3px solid #c1c1c1;
            }
            
            #c3box i {
                font-size: 12px;
                color: #3d5072;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            
            #c3box b {
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #07162f;
                font-weight: 700;
            }
            
            #c3box h1 {
                font-size: 16px;
                color: grey;
                font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
            }
            
            #c3box h1::first-letter {
                color: #2b3547;
            }
            
            #c3box a {
                color: white;
                background-color: grey;
                text-decoration: none;
                padding: 3px;
                margin-top: 4px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
                -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
            
            #cbox a:hover {
                background-color: black;
            }
            
            #c3box:hover {
                opacity: 0.5;
                width: 80%;
                height: 100px;
            }
            
            #c3boxcontent {
                opacity: 0.9;
                -webkit-transition: .7s;
                -moz-transition: .7s;
                -o-transition: .7s;
                -ms-transition: .7s;
                transition: .5s;
                width: calc(80% - 100px);
                height: 100px;
                text-align: center;
                float: right;
            }
            
            #c3box:hover #c3boxcontent {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            
            #c3box img {
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                margin: auto;
                width: 75px;
                height: 75px;
            }
            
            #nav {
                width: 80%;
                height: 40px;
                margin-left: 10%;
                margin-top: 1%;
                margin-bottom: 0;
                text-align: center;
                line-height: 40px;
            }
            
            #nav a {
                font-size: 13px;
                width: 7%;
                height: 40px;
                margin-left: 1%;
                color: grey;
                text-decoration: none;
                background-color: white;
                -webkit-border-radius: 0;
                -moz-border-radius: 0;
                border-radius: 0;
                border-right: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
            }
            
            #nav a:hover {
                background-color: grey;
                color: white;
                border: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <title>Sensational!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id=container>
            <div id=column1>
                <div id=c1box>
                    <h1>Andrew</h1>
                    <b>male</b><br>
                    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/2b/1b/c8/2b1bc8eb8bdb4d8f66ab9c6c0d585350.jpg"><br><br>
                    <i>Born on the 1st January 2016<br>
   White Fur, Long</i>
                </div>
                <div id=c1box>
                    <h1>Sheila</h1>
                    <b>female</b><br>
                    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/b5/9f/87/b59f8728480231a869b262c5df1978d9.jpg"><br><br>
                    <i>Born on the 2nd January 2016<br>
  Brown Fur, Long</i>
                </div>
                <div id=c1box>
                    <h1>Robyn</h1>
                    <b>female</b><br>
                    <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ItSusHyhZQU/UOQ47Cw5UqI/AAAAAAAAPcs/aNr8veiERRQ/s1600/Cute-Black-Pomeranian-Puppies-2.jpg"><br><br>
                    <i>Born on the 29th February 2019<br>
  Black Fur, Long</i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id=column2>
                <div id="nav">
                    <a href="page1url">Page 1</a>
                    <a href="page2url">Page 2</a>
                    <a href="page3url">Page 3 </a>
                    <a href="page4url">Page 4 </a>
                    <a href="page5url">Page 5 </a>
                    <a href="page6url">Page 6 </a>
                    <a href="page7url">Page 7 </a>
                    <a href="page8url">Page 8 </a>

                </div>
                <h2>POMBRAZEN</h2>
                <P>
                    <center>
                        <B>The Pomeranian Breeder</b>
                    </center>
                </p>
                <p>I'll be typing a load of random crap in here, which you can then opt to fill out later on. I hope that works sufficiently - I assumed you'd have your own content to add, that's all. Well anyway there are a call few things that you can do around here to convey for different effects...<br>
                    <i>Wanna see?</i><br>
                    <center><img src="https://www.asnclassifieds.com/im/images-433/3225078-1079260_141099326096688_569905636_n.jpg"></center><br>
                    <p>Well as you can see, <i>images</i> all are given a cute little border around them automatically! <b>AMAZING</b> isn't it? Not really? Well then why not use the link beside to complain about it: <a href="http://www.marapets.com">(jokes this takes you to marapets)</a>.</p>
                    <p>Because I am lazy I am just gonna copy and paste this all over again. bwahahaha<br></p>
                    <h1>After this sweet subheading of course.</h1>
                    <p>I'll be typing a load of random crap in here, which you can then opt to fill out later on. I hope that works sufficiently - I assumed you'd have your own content to add, that's all. Well anyway there are a call few things that you can do around here to convey for different effects...<br>
                        <i>Wanna see?</i><br>
                        <center><img src="https://www.asnclassifieds.com/im/images-433/3225078-1079260_141099326096688_569905636_n.jpg"></center><br>
                        <p>Well as you can see, <i>images</i> all are given a cute little border around them automatically! <b>AMAZING</b> isn't it? Not really? Well then why not use the link beside to complain about it: <a href="http://www.marapets.com">(jokes this takes you to marapets)</a>.</p>
                        <h1>Ahh - and subtitles. That's always fun!</h1>
                        <p>Because I am lazy I am just gonna copy and paste this all over again. bwahahaha<br></p>
                        <h1>After this sweet subheading of course.</h1>
                        <p>I'll be typing a load of random crap in here, which you can then opt to fill out later on. I hope that works sufficiently - I assumed you'd have your own content to add, that's all. Well anyway there are a call few things that you can do around here to convey for different effects...<br>
                            <i>Wanna see?</i><br>
                            <center><img src="https://www.asnclassifieds.com/im/images-433/3225078-1079260_141099326096688_569905636_n.jpg"></center><br>
                            <p>Well as you can see, <i>images</i> all are given a cute little border around them automatically! <b>AMAZING</b> isn't it? Not really? Well then why not use the link beside to complain about it: <a href="http://www.marapets.com">(jokes this takes you to marapets)</a>.</p>
                            <h1>Ahh - and subtitles. That's always fun!</h1>
                            <p>Because I am lazy I am just gonna copy and paste this all over again. bwahahaha<br></p>

            </div>
            <div id=column3>
                <h1>For Sale:</h1>
                <div id=c3box>
                    <img src="https://pomeranian-husky.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Pomeranian-Puppy-75x75.jpg">
                    <div id=c3boxcontent>
                        <h1>Oscar</h1>
                        <i>£500</i><br>
                        <b>AVAILABLE</b><br>
                        <a href="url here please">View Info</a><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id=c3box>
                    <img src="https://pomeranian-husky.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Pomeranian-Puppy-75x75.jpg">
                    <div id=c3boxcontent>
                        <h1>Oscar</h1>
                        <i>£500</i><br>
                        <b>AVAILABLE</b><br>
                        <a href="url here please">View Info</a><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id=c3box>
                    <img src="https://pomeranian-husky.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Pomeranian-Puppy-75x75.jpg">
                    <div id=c3boxcontent>
                        <h1>Sally</h1>
                        <i>£550</i><br>
                        <b>SOLD</b><br>
                        <a href="url here please">View Info</a><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id=c3box>
                    <img src="https://pomeranian-husky.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Pomeranian-Puppy-75x75.jpg">
                    <div id=c3boxcontent>
                        <h1>Oscar</h1>
                        <i>£500</i><br>
                        <b>AVAILABLE</b><br>
                        <a href="url here please">View Info</a><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id=c3box>
                    <img src="https://pomeranian-husky.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Pomeranian-Puppy-75x75.jpg">
                    <div id=c3boxcontent>
                        <h1>Oscar</h1>
                        <i>£500</i><br>
                        <b>AVAILABLE</b><br>
                        <a href="url here please">View Info</a><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id=c3box>
                    <img src="https://pomeranian-husky.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Pomeranian-Puppy-75x75.jpg">
                    <div id=c3boxcontent>
                        <h1>Oscar</h1>
                        <i>£500</i><br>
                        <b>AVAILABLE</b><br>
                        <a href="url here please">View Info</a><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id=c3box>
                    <img src="https://pomeranian-husky.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Pomeranian-Puppy-75x75.jpg">
                    <div id=c3boxcontent>
                        <h1>Oscar</h1>
                        <i>£500</i><br>
                        <b>AVAILABLE</b><br>
                        <a href="url here please">View Info</a><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: I recommend highly to learn HTML syntax and CSS rules...Your source code is sad to see ...

Comment: I recommend highly to learn general manners and respect for people...Your unnecessary rudeness is sad to see...   -  however I appreciate the help despite that.

Comment: It is a well-intentioned advice...no more and no less!

Comment: [Some bug fixes](http://jsbin.com/dohinapise/edit?html,css,output) ... Good luck

Answer (score 0):

there are a few things I would make sure to do that could be the issue.

1. make sure all of your id tags are changed to classes. Id's should only be used once whereas classes can be used as much as you want
   EXAMPLE CSS: #hello{} to .hello{}
2. a lot of the position attributes that you set to your div's are set as fixed
   this will fix the table to the browser position and not relative to other objects.
   positions should either be set to relative or absolute (absolute is closer to fixed then relative. it fixes the object to a position in its parent element)
   EXAMPLE CSS: .hello{display:fixed;} to .hello{position:absolute;}

another side note: when setting an absolute position make sure its parent elements position is set :)

Comment: I've set them to absolute however do you have any idea how to fix this:

Comment: It fixed what I originally asked for, however I am looking to make it so that when the content in a seperate column overflows, that column scrolls WITHIN ITSELF as apposed to the entire screen. Make sense?